# How can I change Chrome scrollbars to the thin scrollbars?

Tags: scrollbars, google-chrome, chromium

The default scrollbars do not properly integrate into the elementary OS design.

[image: Default Chrome scrollbars]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can get thin overlay scroll bars in Chrome by setting the `#overlay-scrollbars` flag to enabled. Go to:

```
chrome://flags/#overlay-scrollbars
```

Comment: Sadly, it seems that this flag has been removed from Chrome. Checked on Chrome version 71

Comment: It is still there, on Google Chrome 74.0.3729.169.

Comment: I'm running chrome 78.0.3904.87 & I don't see the option :(

Answer (score 13):

Install [this extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/elementary-freya-scrollba/dddhhloahgkhcaipmkfjngdalegmcomm) from Chrome Web Store.

Also, you can install [this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/elementary-os-03-freya-ch/faohdknlfnjkeaphndahbpabllhaodnl) theme for better integration.

After all the above steps Chrome looks like this:

[image]

Comment: There's also an alternative [Freya theme for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/freya-theme-for-google-ch/nofpaaefcomkhdkeihhnonlmhajfadgd), but I can't see any differences.

Comment: Still, there are differences. Varies the color of the window title, for your link it looks worse ([1](http://i.imgur.com/8ployz1.png) and [2](http://i.imgur.com/3wWlQkA.png)).

Comment: Can't tell which is which but 1 looks better and more similar to how stock elementary headerbars are styled (they are not flat like in 2). Although I'd prefer the button color to be a bit darker, they look a bit deactivated.

Comment: The extension does not display scrollbars on all websites, e.g. no scrollbars are shown on Google Docs. I marked the chrome:flags answer as the best answer as it provides better compatibility.